# How can I create a new VM pointing to something other than a CD/DVD

Tags: xenserver, xen

I am new to XenServer and want to experiment with adding new virtual machines.  I am running XenServer 6.1 and XenCenter.  I have successfully created a new VM by burning a DVD and during the creation in XenCenter referring to the DVD by selecting 'DVD drive 0' under 'DVD drives on MyServer' under Installation Media, so I know I can create a virtual machine successfully.

I don't want to have to burn a CD/DVD each time I want to install another OS since I am going to be experimenting with a few different OSs.  I would like to be able to install from either a USB flash drive or a new Storage Repository (SR).

So far I have read a lot documentation (both XenServer and Google) but I can't seem to find the answer to my question.  I shared a folder on my windows box that contains the .iso and then tried creating a CIFS SR pointing to that network share, but even though it shows up in XenCenter once I am done creating it and see under status it says OK and Connected I can't use it. Under Installation Media when creating a new VM, I see it but there is nothing selectable under it (for instance, 'DVD drives on MyServer' exists and under that is 'DVD drive 0'. I can select this and this works).

I have also tried loading the .iso on a flash drive.  I can see it under removable storage but cannot figure out how to reference it during a VM creation.  Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  It seems like it should be easy to install from a network folder or usb drive if I have the .iso

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create new VM in XenServer by using a NTFS usb flash drive?](http://serverfault.com/questions/475915/how-to-create-new-vm-in-xenserver-by-using-a-ntfs-usb-flash-drive)

Comment: Before casting more dupe votes on this please be aware that the other question is already closed.

Comment: I just experienced the similar problem, however, as soon as I moved the ISO image to the root of the share that I mounted, the Hypervisor was able to view the ISO images (didn't even have to re-scan). You may want to simulate this once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CIFS is definitely the way to go. Very easy, once it works.

I am not sure which part was the problem, but I am running Windows 7 with Webroot.  I shared a folder (MyWindows7ComputerName\test), created a new CIFS SR.

In XenCenter when I clicked on the CIFS ISO Library -> Storage tab I saw nothing. I could click rescan and nothing would show up.

As soon as I accessed the share from a third computer all my .isos showed up under the storage tab. Not sure why, but I hope this helps someone.  I spent a lot of time on nothing. And once you do this for a share any iso you drop in should show up in a few seconds - it's just that first time that nothing shows up.

Note: All isos must go in the root of the share. You can't have something like MyWindows7ComputerName\test\folder1\myimage.iso

Answer (score 1):

> I shared a folder on my windows box that contains the .iso and then tried creating a CIFS SR pointing to that network share, but even though it shows up in XenCenter once I am done creating it and see under status it says OK and Connected I can't use it.

This is the best way to do what you're trying to accomplish. You should consider posting a detailed question including whatever errors you're seeing and try to get that resolved.

---

I don't think XenCenter has support for using flash drives as ISO repositories (or it didn't when I worked with XenServer 5.5). If you don't mind using the command line tool (`xe`) for managing Xen you should be able to SSH to your XenServer host and proceed. Start by reading the [XenServer 6.1.0 Administrator's Guide](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX134585)  and [XenServer 6.1.0 Virtual Machine User's Guide](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX134587) .

Comment: Good to know that the way I want to go is CIFS - thanks for the advice. I just thought either would be easy but didn't really care either way. I will keep reading and trying some things, but either way I create CIFS (use GUI or command line) results in a CIFS store with nothing under it. No errors are encountered, but I can't see any folders or .isos under the SR.  Not sure what I am missing

Comment: ok, so I got it working by doing almost nothing. Rescan in the GUI didn't do anything, but accessing the share from another computer did. After I accessed the share to verify it worked all the sudden XenServer could see the .iso as well. Will do more testing later to reproduce steps. Maybe its a Windows 7 thing